# For loop with multiple variable

Tags: c++, for-loop

Is it possible for a for loop with 2 variables to stop incrementing only one of the variable when a condition is met ? For example

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < 5 && j < 10; i++, j++)
{
    cout << i << " " << j << endl;
}
```

and the output would look something like

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
4 5
4 6
4 7
4 8
4 9
```

This is my actual code. I wanted the condition for both variables

```
cout << sp.dets.size() << " " << gt.groundtruth.size() << endl;
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < sp.dets.size() && j < gt.groundtruth.size(); j < gt.groundtruth.size() ? j++ : j, i < sp.dets.size() ? i++ : i)
{
    cout << i << " " << j << endl;
}
```

sp.dets.size = 0

gt.groundtruth.size() = 8

It would be nice if the solution works for any number i.e. `i > j or i < j or i = 0 or j = 0`

Comment: Saying "i < 5 && j < 10; i++, j++" is counterintuitive by logic nature of it.

Comment: @abdul, you can define variable inside loop conditions in c99 as well.

Comment: kong, are you programming in C or C++? You should re-tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Hi I am programming in C++. the tag is correct

Comment: @StoryTeller I replied to a comment, but it's deleted

Answer (score 3):

You can use ternary statement to increment variable `i` value. Like below:

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < 5 && j < 10; j++, i<4? i++: i)
{
    cout << i << " " << j << endl;
}
```

This will output the expected result.

Comment: Thanks ! What if I wanted the condition for both variables ? I edited my code above to show another example. Seems not to work

Comment: the `i<5` part of the `for` condition can be removed because `i` can never get larger than 4

Comment: @ karsten: yes right, there is no need for that.
@kong: i think you should compare it to decremented value `j < gt.groundtruth.size() -1` instead of `j < gt.groundtruth.size()` for both `i` and `j` .That seems to be the reason second example didnt worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work,

```
int k = 0;
int val = 4;
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < 10 && j < 10; i++, j++){   
if (i>=val){
    k=val;
    cout << k << " "<< j << endl;
}
else 
cout << i << " " << j << endl;
}
```

Prints this,

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
4 5
4 6
4 7
4 8
4 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator on both variables. Just be sure to change your condition to break only when both reach their destined value

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0;
     i != 5 || j != 10;)
{
   i += i < 5  ? 1 : 0;
   j += j < 10 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

You'll note I moved the increment into the loop body, this improves readability, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to be overly clever by trying to fit all the logic in one line. It't more important that your code can be read by others (and yourself in two weeks' time) than saving a single line. If the incrementing logic of the two variables is more complex than just increasing by one for each loop, put them in seperate lines, like this:

```
while (i<5 && j<10) {
  ...
  // complicated expression calculating new i
  // complicated expression calculating new j
}
```

In your case, you might also flip the logic around:

```
for (int i=0; i<max(sp.dets.size(), gt.groundtruth.size(); i++) {
   cout << min(i, sp.dets.size()-1)
        << ","
        << min(i, gt.groundtruth.size()-1)
        << endl;
}
```